# How can I reply directly to a user's message using Phoenix channels?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I've built the basic chat application showed in the [Phoenix Channels docs](http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/channels). Now I want a way to handle certain messages by replying only to the sender.

Eg, if the user types `/who`, send them (and only them) a list of connected users.

How can I do this?

Comment: I'm using Phoenix 1.1.4

Answer (score 15):

### In Phoenix

The matching `handle_in` function head needs to return a response formatted like this: `{:reply, {status :: atom, response :: map}, Socket.t}`.

For example:

```
  def handle_in("new_msg", %{"body" => "/who"}, socket) do
    user_list = UserList.get # or whatever
    {:reply, {:ok, %{kind: "private", from: "server", body: user_list}}, socket}
  end
```

(If you set `handle_in` to return garbage, like an empty string, the resulting error explains the acceptable return value formats, which is where I learned this.)

### In Javascript

When you `channel.push`, just chain on a `.receive` for the reply.

```
    channel.push("new_msg", {body: $chatInput.val()}).receive(
      "ok", (reply) => console.log("got reply", reply)
     )
```

([Thanks to Manuel Kallenbach for this answer](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phoenix-talk/Dwu1BHvyqLg).)